# Unix Semaphore Issue

Tags: c, unix, pthreads, posix, semaphore

I have been writing test programs regarding thread synchronization for a larger project for school. One of the test programs I wrote was a short snippet of code to test the "semaphore.h" library. The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

//Semaphore
sem_t mutex;

//Critical section variable
int crit;

//Method for pthreads
void* method()
{
    int x;

    //Loop to increment 'crit'
    for (x = 0; x < 5000000; x++)
    {
        sem_wait(&mutex);
        //Critical Section
        crit++;
        sem_post(&mutex);
    }

    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t t1, t2;

    sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, method, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, method, NULL);
    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);  
    sem_destroy(&mutex);

        //This value should be '10000000'
    printf("Value of 'crit': %d\n", crit);

    return 0;
}
```

The final value of the 'crit' variable should be ten-million, but I am only getting numbers close to it, indicating a race condition. I have compared my code to other samples, and it looks right, but I keep getting the same problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: semaphores are really a bad idea for starters on pthread. the `sem_` calls are usually much too low level. they may e.g be interrupted. You'd have to check *all* return values of all pthread/sem functions. if there is an error code, analyse the code and `errno` and take action accordingly. Better reprogram your example with mutex/conditions, if you may. these are the simpler tools that are the "default" control structures in POSIX.

Comment: Although, Jens' suggestions are valid and I agree, I couldn't reproduce your problem. Start by checking all the return values of those sem_ functions.

Comment: I checked the return values, and there is a '-1' issue. This pushes me in the right direction. I would use something other than "semaphore.h", but it is required for the project. Thanks Jen.

Comment: Works fine here: http://rextester.com/XQWQP41080

Answer (score 1):

Your critical section is not locked at all, which hypothesis fits your symptoms well.

`sem_init()` is failing with ENOSYS.  `sem_wait()` and `sem_post()` subsequently fail with EINVAL, and `sem_destroy()` fails as well (probably again with ENOSYS).  Your worker threads are stepping on each other's increments.

Are you on OS X?  That's the most common platform at present that does not support unnamed POSIX semaphores.  Try the [named semaphore interface](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/sem_open.2.html), defined in the same header file, which *is* supported.